# how can you view or edit a database created in netbeans?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, netbeans, migration, sqlite

i'm using Netbeans 6.5 for RoR development. I believe my sqlite3 DB is out of synch with rails migrations. how can I view and manipulate the database (through netbeans or command line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the "Services" tab, you will see the Database node.  Right click on it and select "New Connection".  Follow the prompts through to supply the details of the database you're connecting to.  At some point you will have to supply a Jar containing the JDBC drivers for sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Ruby or it's migrations, but sqlite3 provides command to access database from terminal: `sqlite3 ./database.db`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `script/dbconsole` which will drop you into the command line for your RDBMS (assuming that your `database.yml` file is configured to access your database correctly). Then use SQL to do what you need to do.